# UITableView vertical scrolling issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

I have a frustrating issue with UITableView vertical scrolling.  I have an (apparently) functioning UITableView (table rows displayed properly, I can select rows and the proper action is performed, etc).

However, I cannot fully scroll to the bottom of the view.  I realize that this question has been asked many times, and I have tried to implement the suggestions given in earlier answers, to no avail.  I suspect a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

I realize that the frame size needs to be larger than the contentSize for the tableView to scroll properly and I have tried to ensure that.  Note that I have just picked a small horizontal contentSize for debugging purposes.  I am sure it is something simple...

Here is a code snippet that shows what I am doing.

```
   self.testTable= [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame 
style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    self.testTable.delegate=self;
    self.testTable.dataSource=self;
    self.view = self.testTable;
    NSLog(@"table: Width: %f  height %f ",self.testTable.contentSize.width,self.testTable.contentSize.height);
    self.testTable.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,200);
    NSLog(@"table: Width: %f  height %f ",self.testTable.contentSize.width,self.testTable.contentSize.height);
```

My NSLog calls return this:

```
2013-04-02 13:23:53.332 TestSet[32358:907] table: Width: 0.000000  height 0.000000 
2013-04-02 13:23:53.333 TestSet[32358:907] table: Width: 320.000000  height 200.000000
```

For what it is worth:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)UITableView *testTable;
```

Any advice gratefully received.

Update - am trying this in landscape orientation

Comment: The contentSize have to be bigger than the tableView frame to scroll, but I never had to change the tableView contentSize, it is something automatic deppending on the number and height of the rows

Comment: Never mess with the contentSize property of table view

Comment: Make sure the size if your table view matches it's superview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt depend on the content size but it is because your frame is not correct.check frame of tableview is proper.Issue will be there in height of tableview will be out of the view and the scroll will bounce when the table scroll reaches the bottom

make the frame of tableview using `[tableview setFrame : CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];`

make

Remove

```
  self.view = self.testTable;
  self.testTable.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,200);
```

add

```
 [self.view addSubview:self.testTable];
```

**USE THIS**

```
 self.testTable= [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
 self.testTable.delegate=self;
 self.testTable.dataSource=self;
 [self.view addSubview:self.testTable];
```

Comment: No luck:    Tried to post the changed code but that didn't work very well.

Comment: @jmf1205 ' NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableview.frame));'
 use this line and log the frame and please provide the log in the comment

Comment: 2013-04-02 14:12:18.252 TestSet[32777:907] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}

Comment: is tableview a subview of the main view or some other view?No need for any contensize specification please remove that from code

Comment: @jmf1205 Edited the answer please try this out

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem.  All of the above was being done in the view controller initWithNibName, instead of viewDidLoad.  A silly mistake.

I thank everyone for their kind assistance, however.